# Removing rows following (and including) the first occurrence of a particular column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large pd.Dataframe contains millions of records where `PID` and `Ses_ID` are both index columns, and `Var_3` indicates the occurrence of some event.

| PID | Ses_ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 002 003 | 0.7 0.8 0.9 | 0.5 0.4 0.3 | 0 1 0 |
| 002 | 004 005 006 007 008 | 0.8 0.7 0.8 0.2 0.8 | 0.2 0.1 0.7 0.2 0.2 | 0 0 1 0 1 |

I want to remove/filter out sessions following and including the first occurrence of `Var_3==1` from each person's (indexed by `PID`) records. Thus the provided example would result as:

| PID | Ses_ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 0.7 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 002 | 004 005 | 0.8 0.7 | 0.2 0.1 | 0 0 |

I could iteratively add relevant sessions and corresponding `PID` to a new dataframe but that would be extremely time-consuming given the size of the current dataframe. What would be an efficient way of achieving this? Many thanks!

**Updated situation:** I have found many rows have the same `Ses_ID`. How do I remove sessions following (and including) the first occurrence of a particular column value? So for the example below, both rows for `Ses_ID==005` would be removed because the event of `Var_3==1` occurred in this session.

| PID | Ses_ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 002 003 | 0.7 0.8 0.9 | 0.5 0.4 0.3 | 0 1 0 |
| 002 | 009 004 004 005 005 006 007 | 0.1 0.8 0.8 0.7 0.8 0.2 0.8 | 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.7 0.2 0.2 | 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 |

should be transformed to:

| PID | Ses_ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 0.7 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 002 | 009 004 004 | 0.1 0.8 0.8 | 0.3 0.1 0.2 | 0 0 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use boolean indexing:

```py
# assuming PID, Ses_ID are indices:
mask = df.groupby(level=0)["Var_3"].cumsum().eq(0)
print(df[mask])
```

Prints:

```
            Var_1  Var_2  Var_3
PID Ses_ID                     
1   1         0.7    0.5      0
2   4         0.8    0.2      0
    5         0.7    0.1      0
```

---

EDIT:

```py
g = df.groupby(level=0)
df["Var_3"] = g["Var_3"].transform(
    lambda x: x.groupby(level=1).transform(sorted, reverse=True)
)
mask = g["Var_3"].cumsum().eq(0)
print(df[mask])
```

Prints:

```
            Var_1  Var_2  Var_3
PID Ses_ID                     
1   1         0.7    0.5      0
2   4         0.8    0.2      0
```

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks @Andrej ! I have found many rows having the same `Ses_ID` as they belong to the same session. Is it possible to remove all the rows having the same `Ses_ID` where `Var_3==1` occurs (while removing the following rows)? I have updated the question. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Blue482 You can sort the values in Var_3 in reversed order and then compute the mask. I updated my answer.